# freecodecamp missing letters bug

Tags: javascript, unicode

this's my first time seeking help here. I'm now working on a problem from freecodecamp.com called "Missing Letters," which asks me to return the missing letter from an alphabetical string, otherwise I am to return 'undefined'.

My logic is to first use a for loop to go through all the indexes in the provided string, then use an if statement to find the instance where a certain index's letter's unicode minus its predecessor's unicode is greater than 1.

I was able to solve it using this code block:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {

var string;   

for (i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
if (str.charCodeAt(i+1)-str.charCodeAt(i)>1) {

    string = String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i)+1);

 }

}

return string;

}
```

However, as I tried to be more thorough by adding another condition, the code deosn't work:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {

var string;   

for (i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
if (str.charCodeAt(i+1)-str.charCodeAt(i)>1) {

    string = String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i)+1);

 }
else string = undefined;

}

return string;

}
```

I would like to ask you guys why this's the case? Why did the computer take priority from the else statement over my if condition?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: when you say "take priority from the else statement" - what do you mean exactly- i.e. what was returned (and what did you expect)?

Comment: for example if I call the function fearNotLetter('abce'); I expect it to return 'd',  and it does before I've added the else condition. However after I've typed the else condition, it just goes right to the else, and return 'undefined' without even going through the if statement.

Comment: Unless you are debugging, you do not know it went straight to the else. Perhaps it set your string correctly, but later in your for loop the behavior was not a skip, and string got reset to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

So going with your approach, I think you would want to adapt it to

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {

var string = undefined; //initialize outside the loop to undefined  

for (i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
if (str.charCodeAt(i+1)-str.charCodeAt(i)>1) {

    string = String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i)+1);

 } //no else needed

}

return string;

}
```

Comment: yeah man. I now realise what's wrong. The code worked to the point where I'd found the missing letter, but it kept going and reset the string to undefined. I should've initiated the string as 'undefined' or use a 'break' statement to stop the loop after missing letter was found. Thanks Jeremy!

Comment: ubetcha. By the way, I think you might want to consider i+1<str.length where you have i<str.length so you are not looking beyond the end of the string.